# Rad grid custom filtering

Tags: telerik-grid

How can I activate custom filtering for my radgrid?(I googled but I didn't get any proper response regarding this)
I have a property like AllowCustomSorting  but I don't have any property regarding filtering.
Can any one provide the way how to implement custom filtering?
If possbile give me a sample page then I will understand.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to know about filtering:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-basic-filtering.html

I usually do my filtering/sorting within my stored procedures as that brings huge speed benefits when working with larger tables.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware this is a fairly old question now but [this link](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/radgrid-drop-down-custom-filter.aspx) should help you:

Note that it has a sample project at the bottom of the page.

The property you are looking for is `AllowFilteringByColumn="True"`

[This page](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/filteringtemplatecolumns/defaultcs.aspx) has a sample using a dropdown and a custom filter.